# Javascript - Convert ISO8601 UTC time to client's local time

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using asp.net mvc 5 for my website and I'm sending the date of a transaction as a `DateTime` object from the model to the view in UTC using ISO8601 format- `2019-03-15T22:32:04.9143842Z`.

If I receive `2019-03-15T22:32:04.9143842Z` as a string from the model I need a function that can convert it to local time for the client. So if the client is in PST then it should convert it to such.

Comment: Could you please clarify which portion is a problem - converting ISO8601 to .Net `DateTime`, figuring client's timezone on server, converting ISO8601 to local time in browser? (@DiogoRocha suggested a duplicate but while it is exactly what post is asking it will unlikely help you as you can't know client's timezone on server)

Answer (score 9):

You can simply pass this format to the `Date` object constructor (or to `Date.parse`).

```
var d = new Date("2019-03-15T22:32:04.9143842Z");
```

The `Z` on the end is critical, as it indicates UTC.

You can then use functions like `.toString()` or `.toLocaleString()` that emit local time.   You can find the `Date` object reference [on MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

When run in the US Pacific time zone:

```
console.log(d.toString());
//=> "Fri Mar 15 2019 15:32:04 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
```

Alternatively, you can use a library such as [Date-fns](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns), [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/), or [Moment](https://momentjs.com/) to format your date to a string in a specific way.

Answer (score 1):

This datetime type / standard is iso 8601 . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601
There are lot of different types of possibilities how to parse iso 8601 date with javascript, one of them being

```
new Date(isoDateString)
```

other including packages such as https://github.com/datejs/Datejs (`Date.parse(isoDateString)`) or manually parsing it yourself.
Then you can get the clients timezone and change the timezone to it / or any desired timezone.