# JavaScript date to show readable time component

Tags: javascript, date

I have the following date and unsure how to convert it to DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS, i.e.:

```
"2021-04-23T05:36:59.486Z"
```

From what I can see, the time that was suppled was `15:36:59` which doesn't seem to match `T05:36:59.486Z`

Comment: Are you saying that the time doesn't match the actual time at your location?  It is because time is in UTC

Comment: It's because the `Date()` method will parse the ISO 8601 date format using the browser's local time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above string shows the date in ISO Format and the timezone is "+00:00". Your local timezone may be different. Refer [55246983](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55246983/javascript-convert-iso8601-utc-time-to-clients-local-time)

Comment: It's more useful to use the question title ("*Javascript - Convert ISO8601 UTC time to client's local time*") as the link text rather than its reference number as it gives a hint as to what to expect at the other end. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm new to the answering game here :)

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use the to `toLocaleString` method

```js
const 
  d = new Date().toLocaleString(),
  date = d.split(",")[0],
  time = d.split(",")[1].trim();

console.log(date);
console.log(time);
```

Comment: The output of *Date.prototype.toLocaleString* is implementation dependent and my not be the format you expect. In particular, there may not be any commas to split on.